FILTER formula with both row and column condition resulting in #VALUE error
I have been able to successfully use the FILTER formula to isolate values for columns and rows, and I have used it with multiple criteria as well.
For some reason it does not work when I try to include both a row and a column based filter.
I have managed to get around it by just having a column with the UNIQUE formula there per each entry. The issue with this is that is not a volatile formula and had to drag the formula across the thousands entries that I have...
I am not that good with coding or excel in general so I am a bit out of my depth here (I have attempted to and failed at researching a solution online that I could adapt).
These are the cells that I want to filter Row1 to 6

I would like the column with the unique name to not be a dropped down formula, but to be - similarly to the Cohort one - dependent on the size of the database (to be encased in those blue lines)


Row filter (working):
=FILTER(OfficeForms.Table[Cohort],NOT(ISBLANK(OfficeForms.Table[Cohort])),"")

Column filter (working):
=FILTER(OfficeForms.Table[@[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)]:[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)3]],(NOT(ISBLANK(OfficeForms.Table[@[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)]:[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)3]]))),"")

My attempt at combining them:
=FILTER(OfficeForms.Table[@[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)]:[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)3]],(NOT(ISBLANK(OfficeForms.Table[Cohort])))*(NOT(ISBLANK(OfficeForms.Table[@[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)]:[Your Name (SURNAME, Forename)3]]))),"")


Please depict what you want to get.

It's hard to figure out exactly what you want from your textual description, but to reproduce your output screenshot from your input data, you can use something like:
=HSTACK(TAKE(Table9,,1),BYROW(DROP(Table9,,1),LAMBDA(arr, CONCAT(arr)))) 



Obviously, if your example is not representative of your actual data, this solution may give unexpected results.

If I am not wrong and mistaken from the output posted in the OP, then you could also use the following formula to accomplish the desired output. This doesn't needs to use a LAMBDA() helper function.


• Formula used in cell A8
=HSTACK(TAKE(OfficeForms.Table,,1),TOCOL(DROP(OfficeForms.Table,,1),1))


